# K8s Ingress doesn't redirect properly

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, reverse-proxy, consul

guys. Well, I've a problem that I cannot figure it out by my self.
I've been trying for 2 days to get this working, but, apparently no answer on internet help me.

Context:

K8s baremetal machine with calico.
Consul Helm Chart deployed.
I want to have a ingress in front of it, so, installed nginx-ingress.

The closest code that I could make "work" was this one:

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "example" {
  metadata {
    name        = "consul-ui-ing"
    namespace   = "consul"
    annotations = { 
        "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target": "/$2"
        "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from": "/"
        "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to": "/consul/"
      }
  }
  spec {
    ingress_class_name = "nginx"

    rule {
      http {
        path {
          path = "/consul(/|$)(.*)"
          backend {
            service {
              name = "consul-ui"
              port {
                number = 8500
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns this screen:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get this k8s ingress working properly?